# How can I store a "global" variable without having to persist it in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to be able to access and change a variable on the server that represents a setting. I really don't see the reason to create a class and store it in a database. There will only be one instance of this variable. Would it be possible to have something that is a SettingsDAO that can read and alter a text file or is there a better way of doing things?

Comment: Does the state of the variable need to be maintained on an application restart?

Comment: Also, how do you need to change the variable? Within your application? Or through some external means?

Comment: @smp7d It does not need to be maintained on restart. It would be convenient if it could be maintained otherwise. It will be changed from an admin JSP. I intend to access this through Spring Security eventually. So the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a Spring singleton bean and get it off the context. It will effectively act as a "constant".

Comment: So you say that I should create the Singleton with the variable I want to be changed, define an instance of it in the config, and call it by that given id through context.getBean("id")?

Comment: You don't need to create a traditional singleton. The Spring context only creates only one instance of a bean by default (a Spring :singleton"). Just make sure you always get the object off the context (either directly or through dependency injection).